# Angular: how to automatically re-render when variable change is detected?

Tags: angularjs

I have a controller that has a scope. There's an API call that returns some data and I store it in the scope. My html is supposed to check if there's anything inside that variable and render things differently.

the html is as simple (but not the exact script, of course) as

```
<div ng-if='!ctrl.$scope.some_msg'>
    <p>Some display, contain is not important</p>
    <button on-click=some_func()></button>
</div>
<div ng-if='ctrl.$scope.some_msg'>
    <p>{{ctrl.$scope.some_msg}}</p>
</div>
```

the js I have is

```
some_func() {
    this.callAPI().then( res => {
        this.$scope.msg = res;
    });
```

Now, this function works as intended, and the msg is indeed loaded into `$scope.msg`, tested using `console.log`, but my html is not updated until i perform some other action. In this case, that button will still be there after being clicked, and I have to click once again to make the change on my webpage happen. Why is that?

Comment: read about $scope.$apply, this is exactly what you need, classic problematic

Comment: And if you use $http to do the request, angularjs will wrap your .then callback inside $scope.$apply so you won't have to handle it yourself ;)